# Angular.js with JQuery Mobile, problems with nested listviews

Tags: jquery, mobile, angularjs

I'm trying out Angular.js with JQuery Mobile (JQM) and the JQM-adapter for Angular.js (https://github.com/tigbro/jquery-mobile-angular-adapter). Things are generally nice and dandy, but I have a problem getting bindings to update when I use nested listviews. I've mangled the 'todo'-application to exemplify my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/thostr/yGeQx/3/

Why won't the button label binding update in the click handler (ng-click="task.name = 'changed'")? This seems to work trivially when the list view is not nested, and with plain Angular.js (no JQM, just plain nested ng-repeats).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is solution on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4YXR/1/) help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However I don't see how this answers my question. There is no JQuery Mobile in your example, nor nested listviews?

I've rewritten my program to use multiple JQM pages. Acceptable solution for me, but leaves the question unanswered.